# JavaFX PopUp Drag and Drop

Tags: java, javafx, popup, draggable

first i use **JavaSE 1.7** -> The product i develop for is setting this standard. So i can **not** use the Functions of JavaFX8!

I developed a Custom Menu Item like this:
http://de.share-your-photo.com/7f2f7d74d8

There you can see some triangels! If the triangle shows to the right side i **want to get a PopUp** on the right hand side next to the Menu Item.
My Problem is that the popup should be  **dragable** and it should **not** be possible that the PopUp leaves the Main Stage.

Could you please help me with this Problem? What kind of class should i use to develop the PopUp?

**Maybe is it possible to make a PopUp Object Draggabel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, by myself.
I added a container (VBox) to the popup and makes this one draggable!
With every new Koordinate, i set the x&y coordinates to the new position!

```
container.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(dragAct==true){
                    //DRAG HANDLING
                }
            }
        });
```